# How to generate Swift/Objective-C classes from a DTD file?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xml, swift, dtd

I have a given huge DTD file and I want to generate my classes for an iOS project automatically. Preferably Swift or Objective-C classes. Is there any tool that could do the trick? I did some research and only found generators for Java and C#.

Comment: Have a look at `NSXMLParser`.

Comment: I want to create the Swift class from a DTD in the first place. Populating/parsing a XML file afterwards is not my question.

Comment: So you want to load the whole file in a class? It's just a string, correct? Then you could load the file from disk, and extract the string into your class.

Comment: No, I want the actual Swift class being generated from a DTD. This can't be done during runtime, but beforehand.

Comment: I'm afraid I don't understand, what properties would your class have?

Comment: Serialization to objects isn't the solution for everything.  Perhaps you'd consider using existing DOM objects (like the parser suggested above), and just parse out what you need with XPath as an alternative.